# Bluetooth IC performance improves after resoldering/heating

Tags: soldering, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, latching

This is a very general question and I'm trying to brainstorm and get some insight into potential issues, things to watch out for etc. Unfortunately, I can't share the schematic or the datasheet.

My design uses a Realtek RTL8822CS WLAN and Bluetooth transceiver which pairs with a remote control.

Using a nrf52 dongle I am able to measure the RSSI of the DUT in a test chamber. Below are the results from a **good** unit (one which pairs successfully to a remote).
[image]

And here are the results from a **bad** unit, which does not pair to a remote. In this one case you can see the degraded performance on the lower frequency channels, but this isn't always the case. Some bad units have degraded performance on other channels.
[image]

Simply resoldering the same chip and/or after heating the chip with a heat gun, the performance across all channels improves to nominal levels and I am again able to pair my remote.

Could heating potentially cause the IC to exit some latch up state it's been stuck in? (Edit: power cycling the DUT does not solve the issue).
Additionally, there is a 40MHz oscillator which drives the IC for its PLL circuitry. Because the degradation seems to be frequency related I was thinking that it could be related to the stability of the oscillator.

I would really appreciate any ideas.

Comment: This would really just found like a bad solder job that you fix

Comment: Sure its not some badly specced ceramic caps? These ‘heal’ with application of heat.

Comment: You either need to provide pictures of the solder job or a schematic of this Realtek RTL8822CS - googling it reveals what appears to be a black box encapsulated in shielding. I can't even see the antenna.